# Unicode issues when requesting form

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm using HTML, Flask and MYSQL to populate a table when the user first loads the page. The table displays all the rows along with a checkbox and when a user presses the submit button, I get the rows that were checked.

Current HTML code

```
 {% for row in data %}
 <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="inputSelect" value="{{ row[0], row[3] }}"></td>
      <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
      <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

However, when I try `request.form['InputSelect']` on the flask side, it only gives me one result even if I click more than one checkbox.

What's the best way to create the table so that when I click multiple checkboxes, I can see all of them using `request.form['InputSelect']`

Comment: All your checkboxes have the same name: "inputSelect". You should give a different name for each.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it difficult to parse through then? If a user checks 10 boxes, then I have to parse them all individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask use *MultiDict*. To get the list of items for a given key, you can use [getlist()](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method.

Try this:

```
value = request.form.getlist('InputSelect')
```

Comment: This seems to return a unicode - is there anyway I can convert this into proper tuples since I'm dealing with strings and dateTime objectS?